# Using a GLFW application as screen saver

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, screensaver

I've been working with GLFW/OpenGL for a while, and I just came to think that it would be quite interesting to use such an aplication as a screen saver.

I have not been able to find a resource explaining this, so I am starting to think that the answer might just be a plain 'no', but I wanted to ask anyway.

I would like for this to work on either windows or mac or both if possible.

Comment: A Windows screensaver is just a "normal" program which should accept some specific command line arguments: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/182383 Don´t know about Mac.

Comment: To expand on @deviantfan: Just rename your .exe to .scr and drop it into the System32 folder, and it will appear in the list of screen savers.  Lots of the default Windows screen savers such as the 3D text and 3d pipes are just simple openGL apps.

Comment: This appears to work, however, lets say I wish to use som external resources loaded relative to where the application is run, where shoudl I put these? This  could be textures etc.

Comment: @user1291510 Where you want, as long as the program can find them. Eg. in System32 itself or in a subdirectory of it.

Comment: Could this possibly be done with the same simplicity on OS X? (Sorry for asking again)